# Basic ActiveRecordStore updated_at field not being updated on every request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, session

I'm using the standard active_record_store in my app.  In `environment.rb` I have:

```
config.action_controller.session_store = :active_record_store
```

And my `sessions` table was created with `rake db:sessions:create`:

```
create_table :sessions do |t|
  t.string :session_id, :null => false
  t.text :data
  t.timestamps
end

add_index :sessions, :session_id
add_index :sessions, :updated_at
```

However the `updated_at` column isn't being updated on each request.  It is being updated upon session creation (to the same value as `created_at`, as expected) but not for any subsequent requests.

Oddly, if I declare the following explicit call in `environment.rb` then the field *is* updated on each request:

```
class CGI::Session::ActiveRecordStore::Session
 def before_save
  self.updated_at = Time.now
 end
end
```

Can anyone explain why this doesn't work by default?

I'm running Rails 2.1.0 -- and no, I can't upgrade Rails at the moment! :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you updating the session?  If you aren't updating the values, then I believe the session won't be saved to disk.

```
class WhateverController < ActionController
  def index
    session[:whatever] = true
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi François. Yes I'm updating session[:user] on every request, albeit with the same value